# Select Not Exist

Tags: mysql

this table called category

I want to select records with Sid=3 AND Bid =0 that not duplicated with Sid=3 AND Bid=8

(I want to select the red record in the image)

http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/8127/6opr.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Category WHERE Sid = 3 AND Bid = 0 
AND Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM Category WHERE Sid = 3 AND Bid = 8)
```